# Connect a VirtualBox virtual machine with Ubuntu Server 20.04 to a VLAN

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, vlan

I want to create a game server for minecraft on my home network accessible from outside (my friends pc at their homes).
To do so I created a Virtual Machine with ubuntu server 20.04 and a VLAN on my router.
The idea is to reserve completely the VLAN for the virtual machine in order to avoid external access to my real LAN.

On virtual Box I selected a "Bridge" connection and promiscuous mode only for the VM.
On ubuntu I installed Vlan and 8021q module, then I edited the yaml on netplan folder as follow:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s3: {}
  vlans:
    Minecraft.Vlan:
      id: 123
      link: enp0s3
      dhcp4: yes
```

I tryed also to assign a static IP, but the results is always the same, the VM lose any connection to internet and network.
[image]

Thanks in advance for the help!